# Django using with apache wsgi

Tags: django, apache

I want run Django with apache wsgi. But It gives Forbidden error. 
/etc/apache2/apache.conf code

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/mazlum/Django/modeller/modeller/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/mazlum/Django/modeller

<Directory /home/mazlum/Django/modeller/modeller>
<Files wsgi.py>
 Order deny,allow
 Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>

<Directory /home/mazlum/Django/modeller/statik_dosyalar>
 Order deny,allow
 Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /home/mazlum/Django/modeller>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Show us your error message...

Comment: Thank you for feedback. Message ;
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Comment: Which user does the webserver run as, and does that user have read and execute rights to your wsgi.py?  (and the other directories/files as well...)